# Synchronized browsing between two Dired Emacs buffers?

Tags: emacs, winscp, dired

I use two Dired Emacs buffers, juxtaposed in two vertical panels to copy files from my local computer to a distant server (over SCP). I hit `Ctrl + C` to copy the local file and give the path to the distant server repository. Thought, it's a pain because you constantly have to switch from one buffer to another to browse their content.

Is it possible to *synchronize* the two buffers, assuming the tree repository are the same on  my local machine and on the server. I know it is possible using WinSCP with the [Synchronized Browsing](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_navigate#synchronize_browsing) feature turned on. Édit : Filezilla [also provides this feature](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Using#Synchronized_Browsing).

Maybe [Sunrise Commander](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Sunrise_Commander) could be the right  tool but I don't have tested it yet.

I don't need a graphical tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely possible and not too hard using the Sunrise Commander and [tramp](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Usage) (which is included by default in all GNU Emacs distributions, AFAIK).

Have a look [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Sunrise_Commander_Tips) for tips on how to compare directories in SC, either [superficially](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Sunrise_Commander_Tips#toc15) or [recursively](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Sunrise_Commander_Tips#toc16). Once you have the entries that differ in each directory, you can apply to them whatever operation you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Emacs 23.2 or later, see user option `dired-auto-revert-buffer` and `auto-revert-mode`.

The former refreshes a Dired buffer whenever you visit it.  The latter refreshes buffers periodically.